# Dynamically shorten text to avoid ellipsizes in jetpack compose

Tags: android, text, android-jetpack-compose

I'm looking to implement a calendar-like application including a day-detail screen in Jetpack Compose.
This screen has a TopAppBar, in which i'd like to show the date like `Friday, March 12th 2022`

However, some screensizes i'm targeting can't display that completely, so i would like to gradually shorten the text if necessary:

```
Friday, March 12th 2022
Fr. March 12th 2022
Fr. March 12th '22
Fr. March 12th
March 12th
```

How can i achieve this?
I already know about Text's `onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) → Unit`, however i don't seem able to change the text from there?

Please note:

- For now, the app is german only, and i tried to "translate" the date formats for this question, so please excuse if i used uncommon ones.
- There are a few similar questions using traditional xml-views, but i'm looking for a compose-solution

Comment: I hear you can also use https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/TextMeasurer for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to display different content depending other content size, you can use [`SubcomposeLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#SubcomposeLayout(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function2)): it allows measuring content without waiting view to be displayed and drawn.

Here's a basic example of how it can solve your problem:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Component(modifier: Modifier) {
    val items = listOf(
        "Friday, March 12th 2022",
        "Fr. March 12th 2022",
        "Fr. March 12th '22",
        "Fr. March 12th",
        "March 12th",
    )
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier) { constraints ->
        val noWidthLimitConstraints = constraints.copy(maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE)
        var i = 0
        var placeable: Placeable
        do {
            placeable = subcompose(i) {
                Text(items[i])
            }[0].measure(
                if (i < items.indices.last) {
                    noWidthLimitConstraints
                } else {
                    constraints
                }
            )
        } while (placeable.width > constraints.maxWidth && items.indices.contains(++i))
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Code to test:

```kotlin
var width by remember { mutableStateOf(1f) }
Component(Modifier.padding(100.dp).fillMaxWidth(width))
Slider(width, { width = it })
```

[image]

Comment: @m.reiter Wow, thanks for that! I have a lot of experience using `SubcomposeLayout`, so it didn't take me long, but when you see it for the first time, it can be quite difficult to figure out

Comment: Great example thanks. 

I was looking into this further as my automated tests were turning up matches for composed UI elements which I did not expect to be present when using an approach similar to this. 

I wrote a small test around this sample and logged the semantic tree and it actually contains all the test elements measured, regardless of what was explicitly placed. I'm not sure this answer represents the intended use for SubcomposeLayout, which seems to be to pass on measurements to other children of the layout.

Comment: @Dori interesting, I'm using such technique a lot and haven't faced any performance issues. Now I've [found](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/032d77295ed861cb36c6582b315c5ba7597d063a/compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/Scaffold.kt#L157) a single place (maybe there're more) in compose source code where same approach is used: as you can see they filter unneeded measurables using `takeIf`.

Comment: Also from performance perspective that's the only way I can think of - using `Modifier.onSizeChanged` or similar would require single frame drawing, which would create some glitches. In case of text-only, you probably can use `TextMeasurer`, but it's not scalable to cases when you have more complicated views.

Comment: Could you also share a guide of how can I reproduce this testing behaviour you're facing?