# Split long text dynamically into multiple columns in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, is there a way to have a text be split into either 1 or 2 columns depending on how long the text is? Without counting words. For instance, if the surrounding component is max 800 high, if the text does not fit into one column, without becoming more than 800 high, a second column is automatically created and the text flows into that one.

Comment: Have you checked [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive)?

Comment: Thx. Are you suggesting to use BoxWithConstraints here? I’m not sure it would work because I would like to control layout based on dynamic data, and BoxWithConstraints seems to be more about showing different content depending on the available space.

Comment: Oh, if you need to show a different layout depending on the size of the text, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71996702/3585796) might give you an idea how to do that.